# Create a line when press a button

Tags: vb.net, drawing, system.drawing, paintevent

I want to make an drawing program "in real time". I have two text boxes and a button in my form. I want to enter two values in the text boxes, push the button and the draw the line.

I tried to call from the `b_Click` (`b` is the button) the `Form_paint` but don't know what to do with the `sender` and the `e` parameters.

Is there any way to do this?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim a, c, d, e As Integer



Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    Dim pen As New Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, a, c, 300, 100)
End Sub

Private Sub b_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b.Click
    a = t1.Text
    c = t2.Text
    Form1_Paint(0,??)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    a = 0
    c = 0
  End Sub
  End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the [`Refresh`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the `Form`, not call the event handler yourself. That method will eventually invoke the `Paint` event and its handler.

```
Private Sub b_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles b.Click
    a = t1.Text
    c = t2.Text

    Refresh()
End Sub
```